# How to create a virtual ethernet card for SSH tunneling through USB device? [W7]

Tags: ssh, usb, ethernet, virtualization, tunneling

I have an SSH tunneling that is connected to an USB device that is connected to the Internet.
How can I configure a virtual ethernet card that get everything to 127.0.0.1:1080?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to pipe *all* network traffic through an encrypted tunnel?

If so, I would look at OpenVPN, which should give you the virtual interface/network you want.

(Optionally keep the SSH tunnel if needed, and pipe the VPN traffic to the remote server over SSH, although I am not sure it would be useful)